# How to check table column data type

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to make table configurable. Before that I am making demo component through which I can make a my own configurable table.
I want to pass few things to my table like, `column names` and `data`.

Column Name I want to pass like this:

```
headers = [
    {name: 'Sr.No'},
    {name: 'name', dataType: 'text'},
    {name: 'mobile', dataType: 'number'},
    {name: 'date', dataType: 'date'},
    {name: 'Action'}
  ];
```

the `dataType` above states that this column will have input type `text` when is `editable`, same for `number` and `date` as well.

I want to show input boxes based on this values, but in `<td>` I am not able to check this `dataType` key. I tried this:

> html

```
<table class="row-border border-1 table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let head of headers">{{head.name}}</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tr *ngFor="let tableData of data; let i=index">
        <td>{{i+1}}</td>
        <ng-container *ngIf="tableData.isEditable; else viewable">
        <div *ngIf="tableData.dataType ==='text'">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="tableData.dataType ==='date'">
            <input type="date" >
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="tableData.dataType ==='number'">
            <input type="date">
        </div>
        </ng-container>
        <td>
            <button *ngIf="!tableData.isEditable" (click)="onEdit(tableData)">Edit</button>
            <button *ngIf="!tableData.isEditable">Delete</button>
            <button *ngIf="tableData.isEditable" (click)="onSave(tableData)">Update</button>
        </td>

        <ng-template #viewable>
            <td>{{tableData.name}}</td>
            <td>{{tableData.mobile}}</td>
            <td>{{tableData.date}}</td>
        </ng-template>
    </tr>
</table>
```

> ts file

```
headers = [
    {name: 'Sr.No'},
    {name: 'name', dataType: 'text'},
    {name: 'mobile', dataType: 'number'},
    {name: 'date', dataType: 'date'},
    {name: 'Action'}
  ];

  data = [
    {id:1, name: 'sam', mobile: '8788888888', date: '20/11/2021', isEditable: false},
    {id:2, name: 'joy', mobile: '9788888888', date: '22/11/2021', isEditable: false},
  ]

  onEdit(data) {
    this.data.map((item) => {
      item.isEditable = data.id === item.id;
    })
  }

  onSave(data) {
    data.isEditable = false;
  }
```

Is there any way, so that I can check the column dataType and based on that I am able to show that input box in that cell of row when I click on `edit` button? Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh dear lord have I spent much time in my past to create beautiful and editable tables.
I know how annoying this can be so I took my time and looked at your example.

Here is a quick and very dirty version I took your example.

You need to be able to map the headers to the properties of the data otherwise you can't identify which column represents which values as it is currently hardcoded in your example.

```
 headers = [
{name: 'Sr.No'},
{name: 'name', dataType: 'text', mappedProperty: 'name'},
{name: 'mobile', dataType: 'number', mappedProperty: 'mobile'},
{name: 'date', dataType: 'date', mappedProperty: 'date'},
{name: 'Action'}];
```

Furthermore you need to iterate through the headers in the view template to get the mappedProperty and to figure out which dataType it has.

Here is the possible solution:

```
<table class="row-border border-1 table">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th *ngFor="let head of headers">{{head.name}}</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr *ngFor="let tableData of data; let i=index">
    <td>{{i + 1}}</td>
    <ng-container *ngIf="tableData.isEditable; else viewable">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let head of headers">
        <ng-container *ngIf="head.mappedProperty">
          <td>
            <input [type]="head.dataType" [(ngModel)]="tableData[head.mappedProperty]">
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <td>
      <button *ngIf="!tableData.isEditable" (click)="onEdit(tableData)">Edit</button>
      <button *ngIf="!tableData.isEditable">Delete</button>
      <button *ngIf="tableData.isEditable" (click)="onSave(tableData)">Update</button>
    </td>

    <ng-template #viewable>
      <td>{{tableData.name}}</td>
      <td>{{tableData.mobile}}</td>
      <td>{{tableData.date}}</td>
    </ng-template>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the onEdit function. In my opinion you just need to toggle isEditable. But I am unsure what you were trying in the example so sorry for any misunderstand:

```
  onEdit(tableData: any) {
    tableData.isEditable = !tableData.isEditable;
  }
```

Have fun with the example and if you need any help let me know.

**Here is the running example:**
[image]

**Important: This is way to much to write for each table.**
Do yourself a favore and abstract it into a component and reuse it. Some interface like this should work. And the code is quite similar to the current.

```
<my-table-component [columnDefinition]="headers" [rows]="data"></my-table-component>
```

Comment: But how can we get the changed data. Means through [value] I am not able to get the updated data after click on Update button

Comment: If you need to check if one specific values has changed you may use ngModel and then check for the dirty property or if you want the whole column changes ngModel will do this automatically as it is a Two-Way-Binding. You could replace [value] through [(ngModel)]. Then the values will be updated immediately

Comment: can you please remove this image, because it contains my name :P

Comment: I will.  I also will adjust the data table.

Comment: Hey can you tell me how can I make add button above the table, on click of that I can add rows

Comment: Simply create an add button and then execute a function which pushes a new value to the array "data". Something like this.data.push({isEditable: true, name: null, date: null,  id: this.data.length + 1, mobile: null}). Should work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227401/discussion-between-techguy-and-danis).

Comment: Can you join this chat, I have some doubts